# Is X-23 considered a mutant?

Tags: marvel, x-men

After years of reading X-Men, I noticed something that I had originally missed: if X-23 was cloned using Wolverine's DNA, does this mean she is not technically a mutant? Or does the fact that she was born with these abilities contradict the cloning?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, the Earth-616 version of [Laura Kinney](http://marvel.wikia.com/Laura_Kinney_(Earth-616)) (aka "X-23") is classified as a mutant.**

Laura Kinney was created using a corrupted sample of [Wolverine](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_(James_%22Logan%22_Howlett))'s DNA. The sample was decades old and a few segments - including the Y chromosome - were unrecoverable. To create a viable sample, the DNA was augmented using that of [Sarah Kinney](http://marvel.wikia.com/Sarah_Kinney_(Earth-616)), the project director. The resulting viable sample was the 23rd attempt, thus the X-23 designation for Laura. For the most part, she is considered a female duplicate of Wolverine, although there ARE some notable differences due to the process. For instance, she has a different claw configuration than her genetic "father".

[image]

In the Marvel universe, the term "mutant" refers to any individual of the [Homo sapiens superior](http://marvel.wikia.com/Homo_superior) sub-species. Since Laura has the "mutant gene" in her genetic makeup - just like Wolverine - she is still classified as a mutant despite her origin as a clone.

Another example of this would be the [Cuckoo sisters](http://marvel.wikia.com/Stepford_Cuckoos_(Earth-616)), who are classified as mutants despite being

> enhanced clones of [Emma Frost](http://marvel.wikia.com/Emma_Frost_(Earth-616)).

Comment: Awesome. The bit about X-23 sharing the same genetics as Wolverine was perfect, and I never knew about the Emma Frost/Cuckoo Sisters bit at the end.

Comment: @Howard8614 - when you get a chance, you can accept this answer by clicking the green check mark icon below its voting arrows. This lets others know that it answered the question to your satisfaction.